# JWT authentication doesn't work in website, but works on "postman"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, backend

When I try to authenticate user through tools like "Postman" or "Insomnia" everything works (when I set bearer).

But when I try logging in through website I get error in here:

```
function authenticateToken (req, res, next) {
    const authHeader = req.headers['authorization']
    const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1]
    console.log(token);
    if(token == null) return res.sendStatus(401).send("TOKENS IS NULL");
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user)=>{
        if(err) return res.send(403);
        req.user = user;
        next();
    })
}
```

ERROR I GET:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/users/ 401 (Unauthorized)

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 401
```

Anyone has any tutorials / examples / suggestions to help me out?

Some more of my code to understand situation better:

```
router.route('/login').post(async (req, res) => {
    const user = await Users.findOne({username: req.body.username});
    if(!user) throw Error('Password or Username')
    if(await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)) {
        const accessToken = jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, {expiresIn: 604800});
        res.json({ accessToken: accessToken });
    } else throw Error('Password or Username is incorrect');
});
```

```
router.route('/').get(authenticateToken, async (req, res) => {
    const user = await Users.findOne({username: req.body.username});
    if(!user) throw Error('User do not exist')
    res.json(user)
});
```

Im calling Back-End with axios in my React component

```
const user = axios.get('http://localhost:5000/users/');
```

Comment: What did you have on req.headers when making http request from the browser?

Comment: how to I check that? by console.log(req.headers) that?

Comment: Yes, change console.log(token); to console.log(req.headers);

Comment: {
  host: 'localhost:5000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36',
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  referer: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
}

Comment: The problem is that you are missing the "authorization" header when you make the request from your browser/ui

Comment: how do I add that header?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225587/discussion-between-ballon-ura-and-elvinas-kujelis).

Answer (score 0):

Please initialize config variable where we define token then pass this with axios request.

Example :-

```
const config = {
headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
};

Axios.post( 


'http://localhost:5000/users/',


config
).then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```